# Надёжный способ захвата окон Windows 10

Tags: winapi

Имеется задача захватывать определённые (выбранные пользователем например) окна в Windows 10, в идеале должна быть возможность захватить выбранное окно, при этом не захватывая ничего лишнего, в частности, если какое-либо другое окно перекрывает окно, которое мы захватываем, это перекрывающее окно не должно быть захвачено. Я пробовал искать различные API, которые могли бы помочь в решении этой задачи, однако, к сожалению, пока что ни один API не смог это надёжно сделать.

Самый популярный способ, который везде упоминается -- это использование GDI и связки `GetDC()`/ `GetWindowDC()` вместе с `BitBlt()`. Этот подход отлично работал при включённом Aero на Windows 7 и на приложениях вроде Notepad в Windows 10, однако проблема состоит в том, что "Metro UI Apps" таким способом не захватываются никак, результирующая bitmapка просто чёрная и не содержит ничего. Всё усложняется тем, что большинство популярных приложений (браузеры к примеру) меняют способ рендеринга на Windows 10, поэтому такие вещи как Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox последних версий не захватываются при помощи этого подхода тоже (однако захватываются в прежних версиях Windows). Одним словом, `BitBlt()` как API стал очень непредсказуемо работать в Windows 10, часть окон захватываются, часть окон захватываются частично (не захватывается титульная часть, вместо неё захватывается содержимое окон, находящихся под захватываемым окном), а если попытаться захватить, к примеру, Mozilla Firefox, результирующая bitmap вообще будет содержать исключительно содержимое окон, находящихся под Mozilla Firefox окном.

Также я пробовал использовать `PrintWindow()` и `PrintWindow()` в связке с `BitBlt()`, однако проблему решить не смог.

Возможные другие методы захвата описаны [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen/), однако они, кажется, тоже не подходят (похоже что другие методы не различают окна как таковые и могут захватывать лишь полный экран или части этого экрана).

Мне кажется, что должен существовать надёжный способ захвата таких приложений, поскольку TeamViewer, к примеру, каким-то образом их захватывают.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала передаете фокус окну, двигаете его в угол, делаете скриншот всего экрана, обрезаете, возвращаете окна как было. Пример кода тут > https://github.com/miranda-ng/miranda-ng/blob/master/plugins/SendScreenshotPlus/src/Utils.cpp (функция CaptureWindow c bIndirectCapture = true)

Comment: Спасибо за совет. А можно ли как-то посмотреть как эта функция работает в действии? Я полагаю, что если она есть в сорсах miranda, её, возможно, можно как-то активировать? Я попробовал установить этот IM client, но не нашёл где попробовать эту фичу. Не подскажите? Дело в том, что я проверить насколько это надёжно и "быстро" работает (это должно быть невидимым для пользователя), но подход интересный.

Comment: MirandaNG + плагин SendScreenshotPlus, в главном меню появится возможность делать скриншоты. Работает полностью незаметно.

Comment: Попробовал, в текущем состоянии плагин не смог захватить "Metro UI application", но я полагаю, что это по той причине, что сейчас ведётся захват с DC окна, а не с DC экрана. Дело в том, что мне нужно быть уверенным, что при таком подходе я смогу захватывать окно с FPS ~ 15 и при этом не будет никаких видимых скачков фокуса между окнами, т.е. не будет нарушаться UX.

Comment: Нужно было поставить галку "Косвенный захват" (Indirect) для захвата Metro UI и всяких браузеров. А вот на счет 15fps это вряд ли, тут нужен другой подход.